# Need help with motion package

Tags: motion

I tried MJPEG and this is the output I'm getting on all three cameras with highest stream quality, max frame rate, and frame width x height = 1280 x 720.

Camera 1, 2 and 3 show the below kind of choppiness (It is like a dynamic disturbance on the streams).

[image]

Below is my mask file (I don't want to detect motion. Only to show the stream as it is):

```
P5
1280 720
255
^@^@^@^@^@^@
```

But when I change the stream to YU12, two streams work properly and the third one shows this a grey screen and shows `Unable to open video device`.

Can't figure out what the cause could be

Comment: i think that the camera is looking into a parallel universe

Comment: Could you please add more information with some better details? It's confused me.